# SQL find text in string

Tags: html, sql, replace, charindex

I have a text field in my database:

```
DECLARE @vchText varchar(max) = 
 This is a string<>Test1<>Test2<>Test
```

That @vchText parameter should return like this:

```
  This is a string: 

     1. Test1    
     2. Test2 
     3. Test
```

Anyone think of a good way to correct this. I was thinking the STUFF and CHARINDEX Functions with a WHILE LOOP...?

Something I should also note would be that there might not be only 1,2,3 items in the list there could be lots more so I can't build it so its static and only handles 1,2,3 it should be able to work for any number of items in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with a loop and use the stuff and charindex below.

```
    DECLARE @vchText varchar(max) = 
 This is a string<>Test1<>Test2<>Test


DECLARE @positionofNextX INT = CHARINDEX('<>', @vchText)
DECLARE @nbrOFListItems INT = 1

WHILE @positionofNextX  != 0
BEGIN
    SET @NOTE = STUFF( @vchText, @positionofNextX, 4, CAST(@nbrOFListItems AS VARCHAR(1)) + '. ')

    SET @positionofNextX  = CHARINDEX('<>',  @vchText)

    --increment the list item number
    SET @nbrOFListItems = @nbrOFListItems + 1
END

print  @vchText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Break the string into parts.

1. First part  - `This is a list:`
2. Second part - `1.Test1 1.Test2 1.Test3`

Convert the **second part** into rows using the delimiter `Space`. Then add `row_number` to the rows. Append the `row_number` and column data.

Finally convert the different rows into single row delimited by `space` and append it with the `first part`

```
DECLARE @NOTE   VARCHAR(max) = 'This is a list: 1.Test1 1.Test2 1.Test3',
        @temp   VARCHAR(max),
        @output VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @temp = Substring(@NOTE, Charindex(':', @NOTE) + 2, Len(@note))

SELECT @output = LEFT(@NOTE, Charindex(':', @NOTE) + 1)

SELECT @output += CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col))
                  + Substring(col, Charindex('.', col), Len(col))
                  + ' '
FROM   (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') col
        FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@temp, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
               CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) ou

SELECT @output -- This is a list: 1.Test1 2.Test2 3.Test3
```

Comment: I got this from the output: "This is a list:11.Test11.Test21Test3 "   and I think its because there aren't really spaces in between 1.Test11.Test21.Test3

Comment: @BS123 - So how your input will be.

Comment: @BS123 - Sorry I have no idea on how `HTML` works. If you give me a input string will try to get you the expected output.